# Adding icon in the center of a CSS animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I found a CSS animation that I quite enjoy. I want to place an icon in the center of the animation. I realize that the animation has no real 3D animation happening, as it's just three different shapes rotating. But I was hoping someone with experience can add an icon to the center of them, in-turn making the rotating objects look 3D around the icon.

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdNqKY)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #3C4B57 0%, #1C262B 100%);
}

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 32px);
  left: calc(50% - 32px);
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.inner.one {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  animation: rotate-one 1s linear infinite;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

.inner.two {
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  animation: rotate-two 1s linear infinite;
  border-right: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

.inner.three {
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  animation: rotate-three 1s linear infinite;
  border-top: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

@keyframes rotate-one {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-two {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-three {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="inner one"></div>
  <div class="inner two"></div>
  <div class="inner three"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #3C4B57 0%, #1C262B 100%);
}

img {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 32px);
  left: calc(50% - 32px);
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.inner.one {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  animation: rotate-one 1s linear infinite;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

.inner.two {
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  animation: rotate-two 1s linear infinite;
  border-right: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

.inner.three {
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  animation: rotate-three 1s linear infinite;
  border-top: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

@keyframes rotate-one {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-two {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-three {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="inner one"></div>
  <div id="image"><img id="image" src="http://findicons.com/icon/167482/light_circle_blue?id=167564" /></div>
  <div class="inner two"></div>
  <div class="inner three"></div>
</div>
```